# Writing WHERE output to variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the `WHERE` command as a search feature to find a specific file type within a group of folders, but I can't figure out how to export the results as a variable or something that I can reference to `COPY` the files that the `WHICH` command found. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where command') do ECHO copy "%%a" "destination"
```

Where the `echo` simply shows the `copy` command required. remove the `echo` keyword to execute. I can't specify your destination.

Note that if the same filename appears more than once in the `where` list, you're likely to have the destination file overwritten.

This is a **batch** line - to execute directly from the prompt, use `%` in place of `%%`.

Comment: The error message I get reads `The system cannot find the file WHERE.` 


This is the code i'm pasting into the command line: 


`for /f "delims=" %a in (WHERE /r "c:\users\myname\desktop\" print.txt /f) do copy "%a" "folderfolder"`

Comment: The `where command` must be within single-quotes as shown (ie put a single quote directly after the `(` and directly before `)` ). See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.